# Can I use JDBC to set Micrososft SQL Server read only?

Tags: sql-server, docker, jdbc, clojure

I'm making a Clojure library that runs Microsoft SQL Server in a Docker image. I'm using image 2019-CU14-ubuntu-20.04.

There's a JDBC macro `with-db-transaction` that can take a read-only parameter. This works with a PostgreSQL image, but not with Microsoft SQL Server. Is there some way I can set a connection to SQL Server as read-only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC doesn't have a concept of read-only transactions, but it does support read-only connections (but only as a hint, so it doesn't necessarily require support of the underlying database or driver). Some drivers ignore this hint, while others use it to start read-only transactions.

The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver doesn't support it; the implementation of `Connection.setReadOnly(boolean)` in [`SQLServerConnection`](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java#L4245) does nothing:

```java
@Override
public void setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) throws SQLServerException {
    if (loggerExternal.isLoggable(Level.FINER))
        loggerExternal.entering(loggingClassName, "setReadOnly", readOnly);
    checkClosed();
    // do nothing per spec
    loggerExternal.exiting(loggingClassName, "setReadOnly");
}
```

In other words, no it is not possible to set a connection as read-only for SQL Server.

Comment: Furthermore, if portability is a concern, note that "read only" may have a bizarre meaning. Some MariaDB "select" statements can't be done on a read-only connection - I saw this with recursive CTE's.  At any rate, using an appropriately-limited user account is probably a better solution than JDBC's read-only connections.

Comment: As the maintainer of clojure.java.jdbc and the creator of next.jdbc, I want to emphasize that the amount of database-specific variability in JDBC is truly shocking. Even with the "standard" of JDBC, the behavior differs dramatically from database to database once you stray from the mainstream path...

Comment: @SeanCorfield There are several reasons for this, but the most important one is probably politics and "lowest common denominator" support. That said, I think compared to database support in other languages, JDBC does pretty well.